# How to respond to the error [Error]: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "PFObject contains container item that isn't cached."

Tags: swift, parse-platform

To start off let me say yes, this question has been asked before, however I can't comment or ask a question on the pervious one so I'm stuck but this is it: [How do you store a dictionary on Parse using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343040/how-do-you-store-a-dictionary-on-parse-using-swift) So before I continue let me give some context to my error. Iv'e been using parse for this iOS app I'm making, and in screen 'a' I make an object, then I find the corraponing group object in parse get the array that is stored in the group object, add my item to the array. and then save it all back to parse. Next on screen 'b' I have a table view that grabs all the items and presents them. I know there are no problems with screen 'b' because I've tested it. However it seems that my item is not being added to the group object and it is really frustrating. Then for some reason there is this error when I click screen 'b' to see if the item saved `[Error]: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "PFObject contains container item that isn't cached."` If you would like the code Im using to save the item which seems to be failing here it is. @IBAction func

```
addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (itemName.text != "" && itemDescription.text != "") {

            let newItem = Item()
            newItem.name = itemName.text!
            newItem.descrpiton = itemDescription.text
            newItem.gotten = false
            newItem.rejected = false
            newItem.sender = PFUser.currentUser()!.username!

            let query = PFQuery(className: "Group")

            query.whereKey("objectId2", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil && objects != nil{
                    let obj = (objects as! [PFObject]).first!

                    var items : [Item] = obj.objectForKey("itemList") as! [Item]

                    newItem.group = obj.objectId!

                    items.append(newItem)

                    obj.setObject(items, forKey: "itemList")
                    obj.save()

                }
            }

            itemName.resignFirstResponder()
            itemDescription.resignFirstResponder()
            bottomConstraint.constant = -140
            itemName.text = ""
            itemDescription.text = ""

        }else{




        }

    }
```

Comment: i have some logic to support my theory that it is not saving the array. that for some reason parse cannot save an array with my custom "Item" object in it.

Comment: can i not save a custom object in an array or even as a regular object in parse?